# Making a particular series (line) in an excel-chart invisible

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a graph that has 6 series on it and I want to be able to make each series visible or invisible using a set of ActiveX check boxes. The check boxes seem to be working fine so far, but I can't figure out how to make an individual series invisible. Is there a property of the series that I can use to make it not visible? Google and Microsoft help aren't turning it up for me.

(Granted, that doesn't mean it isn't there...)

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure you can make them invisible or visible; but you definitely can add/remove them.  Would that meet your needs?

Comment: you can also play with their shape fills / line colors to make the "appear" invisible... or there is an option that says `No Line`

Comment: @thornomad Not so much because I'm trying to avoid needing to format them programatically.  If I remove and re-add them they lose all their formatting.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Tried that, but sadly when they are invisible you can still hover over their points and have data pop up.  Considering the hover over is a big feature of this graph...I don't think that's a viable option.  There would be too much phantom data.

Comment: Doug, see my updated answer. I have something I did a while that may work. Sort of a creative solution.

Comment: None of the answers seemed to work for me, so I added my own, at the bottom.,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

Wait, I remember that I have come across this before in the past. A good way to hide the data you want is to hide the actual rows / columns of data being charted. So your ActiveX control won't touch the chart, but rather hide / unhide the columns / rows of chart data.

You will just need to set up your chart data in such a way that it doesn't interfere with any other data that needs to be shown.

**Leaving my original answer for anyone's benefit...**

I just recorded a macro and played with it ...

Got this great result:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select

'Turn it on
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
'Turn it off
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
```

This is eqiuvalent to selecting `No Line` in the Line Color section of the Format Data Series dialog box.

Comment: I think I've tried this, but let me see if I'm correct.  When you say "hide" I think "move the cells somewhere else".  But is there a way to just hide them in place, fundamentally making the values themselves invisible?

Comment: @Doug -> No, I mean `.Range("A1:A10").EntireColumn.Hidden = True` or `.Range("A1:D1").EntireRow.Hidden = True` ...  the equivalent to hiding a row or column manually in a sheet. If you need, I can post an example spreadsheet.

Comment: And that won't effect the ranges I'm using for my series at all?

Comment: @Doug -> If you have the chart data set up properly and you hide the row / column with any given series in it, the rest will still appear.  Try it manually... you will see very quickly.

Comment: @doug ... see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/harxrssnen3518d/ChartHideColumn.xlsx)

Comment: No need, you already solved it.  My heartfelt thanks, I've been working at this for 2 days now and was just getting ready to go to my boss and tell him we'd have to change the requirements.  You have my thanks!

Comment: Though you really should move your first comment there up to your answer, because that comment was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When I get stumped in Excel, I always try recording a macro, a la WWBGD? (What Would Bill Gates Do?)

Here's the result for a bar chart where I set the fill to "None":

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
```

Does that help?

Comment: Perhaps, let me give that a shot.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for the kind of chart that I'm doing.  But I may play around with this a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The above 2 did **not work** for me, in case of `ChartType = xlLineMarkers`. 
What did work was:

```
For Each mySeries In .SeriesCollection
    With mySeries
        .Border.LineStyle = xlNone
        .MarkerStyle = xlNone            
        .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End With
Next
```

However, the legend does still display the line. It is necessary to delete that entry separately.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2013, to make a serie invisible, taking it also out of the legend etc, use the filter option, .
Vba Example:

The Following code Hides / Restores the series by filtering it Out/In of the chart.
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).IsFiltered = True / False

This is equivalent to manually filtering a series in/out using the Ribbon command Design + Select Data, (which is available when the char is selected).

All series options, like dashes colors, markers etc.. are restored unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(linenumber).Select
Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
```

This works great, select the chart than i have 24 lines, with a listview with checkboxes and with 24 entries. Click on 1 and it disapears, click again and its back. You alsow see the line dis- and appear in the legend.